# Codeigniter $this->session->... not loading (failing) when adding constructor to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am autoloading the 'session library' using autoload.php.

I am setting my user data in my controller with the following code in my `Users/Login` method.

```
$teacher_data = [
    'teacher_id' => $user_id,
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => true
];

$this->session->set_userdata($teacher_data);
```

Now I simply want to check whether a user is logged in on my restricted pages using the following...

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('login_in')) {
    redirect('home/login');
}
```

In my other controller, called 'Classes' I have the following code...

```
class Classes extends CI_Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('login_in')) {
            echo 'not logged in';
        }
    }
}
```

The code redirects a user back to the login if they dont have permission to view the page, great... however when I add in a constructor... even an empty one like this...

```
class Classes extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function create()
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('login_in')) {
            echo 'not logged in';
        }
    }
}
```

**I get a fatal error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: Classes::$session Filename: controllers/Classes.php Line
>   Number: 12 Backtrace: File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\toucan_app\App\controllers\Classes.php Line: 12
>   Function: _error_handler File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\toucan_app\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\toucan_app\App\controllers\Classes.php on line
>   12 A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Call to a
>   member function userdata() on null Filename: controllers/Classes.php
>   Line Number: 12 Backtrace:

Why is the constructor causing errors? Ultimately I want to add the 'is logged in' check to the class constructor so that I don't have to add it to each single method and thereby protect an entire class.

Comment: I have no idea if I'm even on the mark here, I've never used CI before, but I assume you need to call `parent::__construct()` in the child class. Parent constructs are not implicitly called when extending a class, they need to be explicitly called. Welp, I was right,see [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php#L66).

Comment: It is always best to check session like this `$this->session->userdata('login_in') == TRUE` and load the session library manually and check whether working.

Comment: @ Andrew, absolutely spot on, I will accept your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent `__constructs` are not implicitly called when a child class has a `__construct` method of it's own.

You need to call `parent::__construct()` in the child class's construct in order for it to work properly.

See [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php#L66) for the code related to the CodeIgniter's Controller construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code in set data in session variable :

```
$teacher_data = array(
    'teacher_id' => $user_id,
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata($teacher_data);
```

after you can check login login variable:

```
class Classes extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            echo 'not logged in';
        }
    }
}
```